# How can I get results from multiple models with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some models : User/Like/Dislike...

```
class Like(models.Model):
""" Like """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    movie_id = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Dislike(models.Model):
""" Dislike """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    movie_id = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I get results like this with Django REST Framework by movie_id list and current user?

movie_id = [11111,22222,33333,44444]

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "movie_id": 125405, 
        "like": True, 
        "dislike": False,
    }, 
    ...
    ]
}
```

LikeSerializer:

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'movie_id', 'created')


class LikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Like
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

DisLikeSerializer:

```
class DislikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Dislike
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'movie_id', 'created')


class DislikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Dislike
    serializer_class = DislikeSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Thanks...

Comment: show code of your `LikeViewSet` and `DislikeViewSet` class.

Comment: added answer . try it . let me knw . working or not . not tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom field to response .

Here we can't use `like` . as its reserved keyword in python . See this code . implement same for dislike .

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField('no_likes_get')

    def no_likes_get(self, like_obj):
        return Like.objects.filter(movie_id = like_obj.movie_id).count()

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'movie_id', 'likes')
```

Comment: thks for your answer, i have changed my models, Status:like/dislike/etc.

Comment: i've never used SerializerMethodField, this time i try it , it's  awesome!